# Share table between two jobs

Tags: java, apache-flink

I want to create a table (based on DataStream) and share it between many jobs. I want to create something like whitelist and query this list in another job(s).

Is it possible? As I understand the table is assigned to TableEnvironment. And each job has own TableEnvironment.

How can share this 'state'?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is possible to share the Table across multiple separate Jobs. The best solution I can think of is using a proper `TableSource` like for example `CsvTableSource` or `KafkaJsonTableSource` to register the table for each job. But this won't give You really sharing the state since If You modify the `Table` in one job the changes won't be automatically propagated. I am not sure what is Your usecase and if the `TableSource` will fit Your needs.

Comment: My use case - one job to modify while list, n jobs that have to use this list